# Object is currently in use elsewhere.parallel programing in c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have this code to process image pixels by parallel.for . but shows this ERROR
"Object is currently in use elsewhere"
please help me.
thank you.

---

```
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
int[,] a = new int[bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height];
Color cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4, cc5, cc6, cc7, cc8, cc9;

pictureBox1.Image = bmp2;

for (int i1 = 2; i1 < bmp2.Width - 2; i1++)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(2, bmp2.Height - 2, j1 =>
    //for (int j1 = 2; j1 < bmp2.Height - 2; j1++)
    {
        cc1 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1 - 1, j1 - 1);
        cc2 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1 - 1, j1);
        cc3 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1 - 1, j1 + 1);
        cc4 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1, j1 + 1);
        cc5 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1 + 1, j1 + 1);
        cc6 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1 + 1, j1);
        cc7 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1 + 1, j1 - 1);
        cc8 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1, j1 - 1);
        cc9 = bmp2.GetPixel(i1, j1);
        int[] zr = new int[9] { cc1.R, cc2.R, cc3.R, cc4.R, cc5.R, cc6.R, cc7.R, cc8.R, cc9.R };
        int[] zg = new int[9] { cc1.G, cc2.G, cc3.G, cc4.G, cc5.G, cc6.G, cc7.G, cc8.G, cc9.G };
        int[] zb = new int[9] { cc1.B, cc2.B, cc3.B, cc4.B, cc5.B, cc6.B, cc7.B, cc8.B, cc9.B };
        sort(zr);
        sort(zg);
        sort(zb);
        //      bmp2.SetPixel(i1, j1, Color.FromArgb(zr[5], zg[5], zb[5]));
    });
}
```

Comment: When you run a loop in parallel, the work inside loop should be independent of each other. Here, because of j1-1, j1, j1+1 etc. multiple threads might try to access same pixel objects!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8650850/880990

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap is not thread-safe. Well, it's really *is*, because when you try to access it from several threads, you will get exception like you do. To do operations like you do on it from multiple threads, use LockBits and UnlockBits methods and work with raw data.

P.S: in addition to that, GetPixel is *very* slow, so if you do any serious things, avoid it anyway.