# C# Using multiple threads to complete a single task

Tags: c#, multithreading

Good day everyone.

I've got a question revolving C# and threads, I'm still new to threading and I've got an assignment based on threading. My goal is to let a user specify an amount of threads, and based on that, that's how many threads the application needs to use to complete the task.

My task is to blur an image with a median 3 x 3 matrix. That part I managed to get down (probably not the most efficient code) but now I need to let a variable amount of threads run the blur method and I'm completely lost on it.

Here is my method:

```
    public void Blur(Bitmap bmpInput)
    {

        Bitmap temp;
        float sumR, sumB, sumG;
        Color c;

        temp = bmpInput;

        for (int i = 0; i <= bmpInput.Width - 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= bmpInput.Height - 3; j++)
            {
                sumB = 0;
                sumG = 0;
                sumR = 0;
                for (int x = i; x <= i + 2; x++)
                    for (int y = j; y <= j + 2; y++) 
                    {
                        c = bmpInput.GetPixel(x, y);
                        sumR = sumR + c.R; 
                        sumG = sumG + c.G;
                        sumB = sumB + c.B;
                    }

                byte colorR = (byte)(sumR / 9);
                byte colorG = (byte)(sumG / 9);
                byte colorB = (byte)(sumB / 9);
                temp.SetPixel(i + 1, j + 1, Color.FromArgb(colorR, colorG, colorB));

            }
        temp.Save("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\whatever.jpg");

    }
```

And here is another method which does the same thing (although a bit faster)

```
    public static Bitmap MedianFiltering(Bitmap bm)
    {
        List<byte> termsList = new List<byte>();

        byte[,] image = new byte[bm.Width, bm.Height];



        //applying Median Filtering 
        for (int i = 0; i <= bm.Width - 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= bm.Height - 3; j++)
            {
                for (int x = i; x <= i + 2; x++)
                    for (int y = j; y <= j + 2; y++)
                    {
                        termsList.Add(image[x, y]);

                    }
                byte[] terms = termsList.ToArray();
                termsList.Clear();
                Array.Sort<byte>(terms);
                Array.Reverse(terms);
                byte color = terms[4];
                bm.SetPixel(i + 1, j + 1, Color.FromArgb(color, color, color));
            }
        return bm;

    }
```

At this point I was thinking of "splitting" the image up and letting each thread apply the method to a part of the image.

My question: How do I implement threads into my program. I have never worked with threads before and most online guides look like Greek to me.

Comment: So....what is your question, exactly?

Comment: If you want speed improvements, work directly on the bitmap data, don't use `bm.SetPixel(i + 1, j + 1, Color.FromArgb(color, color, color));`.

Comment: "At this point I was thinking of "splitting" the image up and letting each thread apply the method to a part of the image." Sounds like a good plan. What's the question?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to implement threading, I've never worked with threads so I was hoping that someone could perhaps tell me how to implement threads in this scenario.

Comment: There are countless tutorials on threading out there. I don't know why you'd expect something better from a Q&A site unless you're hoping someone does the work for you.

Comment: I have not done this but I'm not sure threads really improve performance when working with *one* image? I googled this for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650784/c-sharp-threaded-image-processing

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497537/allow-an-image-to-be-accessed-by-several-threads

Comment: Yet more: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335651/parallel-image-processing-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

we can use task library with queuing concept.  As Task library uses cores efficiently.
let us have global BlockingCollection for storing all the incoming Bitmap images.

[BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) is threadSafe Collection

```
BlockingCollection<Bitmap> incomingBitmaps = new BlockingCollection<Bitmap>();
```

And one more global BlockingCollection for processed bitmap images.

```
BlockingCollection<Bitmap> processedBitmaps = new BlockingCollection<Bitmap>();
```

let us have three methods which will be responsible
 for creating task/threads
 reading incoming bitmaps and storing to incomingBitmaps queue
 processed bitmaps will be strored to processedBitmaps queue

```
   BlockingCollection<Bitmap> incomingBitmaps = new BlockingCollection<Bitmap>();
   BlockingCollection<Bitmap> processedBitmaps = new BlockingCollection<Bitmap>();
public static void  SpawnThreads()
 {
 List<Task> ReaderTasks = new List<Task>();
TaskFactory tfReader = new TaskFactory();

public List<Task> ProcessTasks = new List<Task>();
public TaskFactory tfProcess = new TaskFactory();

//you can create threads as many you want
 for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
 {
ReaderTasks .Add(tfReader.StartNew(() => ReadBitmaps());
}
 for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
 {
ProcessTasks.Add(tfProcess.StartNew(() => MedianFiltering());
}
}
public static void ReadBitmaps()
    {
//logic to get bitmap images
Bitmap bmp= GetBitmapImage();
incomingBitmaps.Add(bmp);
}

public static void MedianFiltering()
    {
 foreach (var bm in incomingBitmaps.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
        List<byte> termsList = new List<byte>();

        byte[,] image = new byte[bm.Width, bm.Height];

        //applying Median Filtering 
        for (int i = 0; i <= bm.Width - 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= bm.Height - 3; j++)
            {
                for (int x = i; x <= i + 2; x++)
                    for (int y = j; y <= j + 2; y++)
                    {
                        termsList.Add(image[x, y]);

                    }
                byte[] terms = termsList.ToArray();
                termsList.Clear();
                Array.Sort<byte>(terms);
                Array.Reverse(terms);
                byte color = terms[4];
                bm.SetPixel(i + 1, j + 1, Color.FromArgb(color, color, color));
            }
processedBitmaps.Add(bm);
}
  }
```

we can take processedBitmaps for UI binding.